# vim with python plugins crashes on macOS high sierra

Tags: python, vim, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading to macOS high sierra, vim began to crash with the plugins need python. I am getting the below error whenever i activated a python plugin. For example, i use tern for vim for javascript files. When i activate this plugin, vim opens successfully but it crashes when i open a javascript file.

I have reinstall vim and python with brew. It did not work. I have also build vim from source, it did not work either.

> Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV

Comment: Did you resolve this? Thx

Comment: nope, i switched to neovim.

Answer (score 0):

I had vim crashing after a `brew upgrade` which also upgraded the python version. Reinstallation did not help, but reinstalling all the plugins (and therefore updating them) did help.
Especially rebuilding `YouCompleteMe` was key.